# How to get the monthly average of a sales

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, range, average

Hello Stackoverflow Community,
I am struggling to try and get the monthly average of sales. I know that in order for me to get the current month to date I could just filter for a specific date range but how would someone go about getting the monthly average of sales or any specific integer type. The code on the bottom is the code that I used to find the monthly average but it just showed me the average amount of sales that were made each month.

`df.groupby(pd.PeriodIndex(df['Date'], freq="M"))['sales'].mean()`

What I am trying to do is find out what is the average amount of sales that they make on a monthly bases. Could someone please help me figure this out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The above command will return the average sales made for each month.

However, it appears that you are simply looking for the average sales across all months.

In this regard, it is simply a matter of converting the data yielded from the above command into an array and then calculate the average using numpy.

To use another example, suppose there exists an array of dates with recorded temperatures.

The following yields the average temperature in a given month:

```
>>> data=df.groupby(pd.PeriodIndex(df['date'], freq="M"))['temp'].mean()
>>> data

date
2019-10     2.000000
2019-11     5.000000
2020-01     3.025000
...
2023-06    23.552381
2023-07    16.975000
Freq: M, Name: temp, dtype: float64
```

However, calculating the overall average across these months can be performed as follows:

```
>>> data=np.array(data)
>>> data

array([ 2.        ,  5.        ,  3.025     ,  5.5625    ,  2.7       ,
       19.30652174, 19.4       , 25.42857143, 10.7       , 11.68235294,
       ...
       2.13551402,  5.55135135,  8.48095238,  8.49677419, 12.48571429,
       23.55      , 23.55238095, 16.975     ])

>>> np.mean(data)
13.508786668026012
```

The mean value of 13.5 in this example represents the average calculated across all months.

Comment: Thank you so much for your response this helped out a lot